# How to get this soap header and syntax in php

Tags: php, soap, namespaces

I need to achieve the following

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:ret="http://retailexpress.com.au/">
  <soapenv:Header>
  <ret:ClientHeader>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <ret:ClientID>9bf6dd42-35b9-46dd-948a-1c3c91906caa</ret:ClientID>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <ret:UserName>wsi</ret:UserName>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <ret:Password>wsipass</ret:Password>
  </ret:ClientHeader>
```

What I get:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:ns1="http://retailexpress.com.au/" xmlns:ns2="namespace">
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
 <ns2:ClientHeader>
 <ns1:UserName>wsi</ns1:UserName>
 <ns1:Password>wsipass</ns1:Password>
 <ns1:ClientID>9bf6dd42-35b9-46dd-948a-1c3c91906caa</ns1:ClientID>   
 </ns2:ClientHeader>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
```

If I change the two instances of "ns2:ClientHeader" to ns1:ClientHeader, then the code works perfectly and I get the necessary output. But I am not sure how to avoid that from adding ns2 instead of ns1 in there.

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
$client_id='9bf6dd42-35b9-46dd-948a-1c3c91906caa';
$wsdl_url="http://v2wsisandbox.retailexpress.com.au/dotnet/admin/webservices/v2/webstore/service.asmx?wsdl";
$user='wsi';
$pass='wsipass';    

$options_arr=array('trace' => TRUE);

$client = new SoapClient($wsdl_url, $options_arr);

$headerParams = array('ns1:UserName'    => $user,
                  'ns1:Password'      => $pass,
                  'ns1:ClientID'      => $client_id);

$soapStruct = new SoapVar($headerParams, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT);

$header = new SoapHeader('namespace', 'ClientHeader', $soapStruct, false);

$client->__setSoapHeaders($header);
```

I can't figure it out. Been trying for the past few days, searching many posts before I am here finally. Hope you guys help me as you always do.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

See this comment:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.setsoapheaders.php#93460

So it would be like:

```
$headerbody = array('UsernameKey'=>array('Username'=>$UserID,
                                         'Password'=>$Pwd)); 
$header = new SOAPHeader($ns, 'RequestorCredentials', $headerbody);       

//set the Headers of Soap Client.
$soap_client->__setSoapHeaders($header);
```

Comment: yeah, I tried that, but that did not add anything to header at all. What is the value of $ns? And my problem is it forms ns1 and ns2. How to avoid that

Comment: I tried that example, but it did not resolve forming both ns1 and ns2. I just want ns1. How should I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Your namespace in SoapHeader needs to match the namespace for ns1. In your case it is:

```
xmlns:ns1="http://retailexpress.com.au/"
```

So your SoapHeader namespace should be:

```
http://retailexpress.com.au/
```

Example:

```
$header = new SoapHeader('http://retailexpress.com.au/', 'ClientHeader', $soapStruct, false);
```